# event.params is always empty when testing Cloud Functions locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Consider the following simple onCreate trigger function.

```
exports.sampleFunction = functions.database.ref('/foo/{recordID}')
.onCreate(event => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

I am using `firebase experimental:functions:shell` to invoke the function locally for testing using the following command:

```
sampleFunction('/TEST-DATA/', {params: {recordID: "Test Param Value"}});
```

And I'm getting the following output, notice that `event.params` is empty.

```
info: { eventId: '4282b14f-edea-4497-8bee-b045023b0a84',
  timestamp: '2017-10-15T16:12:59.812Z',
  data: 
   DeltaSnapshot {
     app: 
      FirebaseApp {
        firebaseInternals_: [Object],
        services_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '__admin__',
        options_: [Object],
        database: [Function: bound ],
        auth: [Function: bound ],
        messaging: [Function: bound ],
        INTERNAL: [Object] },
     adminApp: 
      FirebaseApp {
        firebaseInternals_: [Object],
        services_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '__admin__',
        options_: [Object],
        database: [Function: bound ],
        auth: [Function: bound ],
        messaging: [Function: bound ],
        INTERNAL: [Object] },
     _path: '/foo/Test Param Value',
     _data: null,
     _delta: '/TEST-DATA/',
     _newData: '/TEST-DATA/' },
  eventType: 'providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create',
  resource: 'projects/_/instances/silk-39c1f/refs/foo/Test Param Value',
  auth: { admin: true },
  params: {} }
info: Execution took 10 ms, user function completed successfully
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  Params are showing up fine for me.  If you have a bug report, please file that at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I've just filed a bug report. In the mean time params are behaving as expected in production.